# How to insert a variable into .replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable called 'link', that I would like to insert like first parameter 
of '.replace()' function of javascript, I did in this manner, but doesn't run:

```
var link = "http:// etc ...";
previewPDF(link);

function previewPDF(link) {
    $('div:contains(linkPdf)').html(function () {
        return $(this).html().replace(link, "<b><span style='color:red'>linkPdf</span></b>"); 
      });
}
```

I tried to pass a word (link) like so : ....replace(/link/g, " and Run !
But I need to pass a variable.
Can you help me  ?
Thanks

Comment: Use `new RegExp( link, 'g' )`, the long version of `/mytext/g`?

Comment: Could you explain better ? .replace(new RegExp(link, 'g'), "<b><span> .. etc .. ") ?

Comment: This constructor takes two strings, one with what you want to search for and the other with what kind of flags. So yes, `string.replace( new RegExp( searchVariable, 'g' ), 'myreplacementStringOrFunction' )` will do the trick.

Comment: I did so: $('div:contains(linkPdf)').html(function () {
     return $(this).html().replace(new RegExp( link, 'g' ), "<b><span style='color:red'>linkPdf</span></b>"); 
   }); but doesn't run

Comment: With "doesn't run", do you mean nothing gets replaced or it throws errors?

Comment: nothing gets replaced

Comment: Then it's actually more likely that no matches are found. Without the input you are using and the output you are expecting there is no way to help you any further...

Answer (score 3):

Simple use the `RegExp` constructor to use variables inside your patterns:

```
new RegExp( myVariable, 'g' )
```

If you variable is defined as `"hello"`, this is the same as

```
/hello/g
```

Here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Example (you can see both sentences replace the same word, the patterns are matching)

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById( 'p1' );
var p2 = document.getElementById( 'p2' );

var word = 'fox';
var replacement = 'Lady Gaga';
var direct = /fox/g;
var regex = new RegExp( word, 'g' );

p1.textContent = p1.textContent.replace( direct, replacement );
p2.textContent = p2.textContent.replace( regex, replacement );
```

```html
<p><strong>Direct syntax</strong></p>
<p id="p1">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>

<p><strong>RegExp constructor</strong></p>
<p id="p2">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

Comment: I followed your advise, but in my case it doesn't run: $('div:contains(linkPdf)').html(function () {
     return $(this).html().replace(new RegExp( link, 'g' ), "<b><span style='color:red'>linkPdf</span></b>"); 
   });